# How to display vlc video from small screen to another vlc big screen "vlcplugin21"

Tags: c#, winforms, video

I'm trying to display a video in a big screen when I click on button "view video" after loaded it from windows in a small screen via vlc player "vlcplugin21" in Windows Form Application

the following is my code to load video from windows and display it via vlc player:

```
    public void readVLC1()
    {
        ofd.Filter = "All Files (*.*) | *.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            VLC1.playlist.items.clear();
            VLC1.playlist.add("file:///" + ofd.FileName,ofd.SafeFileName, null);              
            txt_VideoName.Text = ofd.SafeFileName;

        }
    }
```

I want to click on another button for example "view video in full screen"
and it will display the same video to a another big vlc screen.

any help??